# Data Wrangling with dates and coorinates, shifting columns to create sf_linestrings per group in R

Tags: r

**My Data:**

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

#test data columns
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
start_date <- ymd_hms(c("2022-06-12 10:00:00", "2022-06-12 10:06:00", "2022-06-12 10:15:00", "2022-06-12 10:18:00", 
                        "2022-06-12 10:01:00", "2022-06-12 10:05:00", "2022-06-12 10:08:00", "2022-06-12 10:15:00", 
                        "2022-06-12 10:00:00", "2022-06-12 10:05:00", "2022-06-12 10:20:00"))
end_date <-   ymd_hms(c("2022-06-12 10:05:00", "2022-06-12 10:10:00", "2022-06-12 10:25:00", "2022-06-12 10:20:00", 
                        "2022-06-12 10:09:00", "2022-06-12 10:10:00", "2022-06-12 10:10:00", "2022-06-12 10:20:00", 
                        "2022-06-12 10:00:00", "2022-06-12 10:13:00", "2022-06-12 10:26:00"))
start_lon <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4)
start_lat <- c(1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1)
end_lon   <- c(2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1)
end_lat   <- c(0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)

#creating tibble
data <- tibble(ID, start_date, end_date, start_lon, start_lat, end_lon, end_lat)
```

```
# A tibble: 11 × 7
      ID start_date          end_date            start_lon start_lat end_lon end_lat
   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>                  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1 2022-06-12 10:00:00 2022-06-12 10:05:00         1         1       2       0
 2     1 2022-06-12 10:06:00 2022-06-12 10:10:00         1         3       2       3
 3     1 2022-06-12 10:15:00 2022-06-12 10:25:00         2         3       2       1
 4     1 2022-06-12 10:18:00 2022-06-12 10:20:00         3         2       3       1
 5     2 2022-06-12 10:01:00 2022-06-12 10:09:00         1         1       1       3
 6     2 2022-06-12 10:05:00 2022-06-12 10:10:00         3         2       1       1
 7     2 2022-06-12 10:08:00 2022-06-12 10:10:00         2         3       1       1
 8     2 2022-06-12 10:15:00 2022-06-12 10:20:00         2         3       3       1
 9     3 2022-06-12 10:00:00 2022-06-12 10:00:00         3         4       2       1
10     3 2022-06-12 10:05:00 2022-06-12 10:13:00         2         2       4       2
11     3 2022-06-12 10:20:00 2022-06-12 10:26:00         4         1       1       3
```

**What I want:**
Lines are to be created for each ID group. The lines are to be generated according to the time course of the points with the coorsinates lon and lat. There are always two points for each path (start and end) if the start point of a following path is before the end point of a previous path, this start point should be taken in between.

```
#Goal
ID1_path_lon <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2)
ID1_path_lat <- c(1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1)
line_ID1 <- st_linestring(cbind(ID1_path_lon, ID1_path_lat))

ID2_path_lon <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)
ID2_path_lat <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1)
line_ID2 <- st_linestring(cbind(ID2_path_lon, ID2_path_lat))

ID3_path_lon <- c(3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1)
ID3_path_lat <- c(4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
line_ID3 <- st_linestring(cbind(ID3_path_lon, ID3_path_lat))

plot(line_ID1, axes = TRUE)
plot(line_ID2, axes = TRUE)
plot(line_ID3, axes = TRUE)
```

**My first attempts:**
My idea is to rebuild the data so that there is only one column for the date and two for the coordinates. This worked, but I get warnings, which makes me doubt if my solution is the best. Furthermore I have difficulties to sort by the date per group and then convert the whole thing as sf_linestring.

```
lines <- data %>% pivot_longer(cols = start_lon:end_lat) %>% 
  mutate(date = if_else(str_detect(name, "^start"), start_date, end_date)) %>%
  mutate(latlon = if_else(str_detect(name, "lat$"), "lat", "lon")) %>%
  select(ID, latlon, value, date) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = latlon,
              values_from = value) %>%
  unnest(cols = lon:lat) %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  st_linestring(rbind(lon, lat)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

with the pivot_wider function I get a Warning message:
Warnmeldung:

```
Values from `value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
* Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} %>%
    dplyr::group_by(ID, date, latlon) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    dplyr::filter(n > 1L)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the `pivot_longer()` like this, this task becomes quite easy:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

data |> 
  pivot_longer(start_date:end_lat, 
               names_sep = "_", 
               names_to = c("time",".value")
               ) |> 
  arrange(ID, date) |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  summarize(line = st_sfc(st_linestring(cbind(lon,lat))))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>      ID                                     line
#>   <dbl>                             <LINESTRING>
#> 1     1 (1 1, 2 0, 1 3, 2 3, 2 3, 3 2, 3 1, 2 1)
#> 2     2 (1 1, 3 2, 2 3, 1 3, 1 1, 1 1, 2 3, 3 1)
#> 3     3           (3 4, 2 1, 2 2, 4 2, 4 1, 1 3)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Sometimes it's just so easy but you can't see it. Thank You so much @shs.

Comment: I ran into a problem with the group_by function while trying around. After resetting everything I only get one linestring instead of three. It looks like there is no grouping at all and the summarize function summarizes the whole tibble.

Comment: After I restarted rstudio and use only the necessary libraries everything works. But as soon as I load the plyr library it doesn't group anymore.

Comment: `plyr` is a retired predecessor package of the `tidyverse`. It has a number of namespace conflicts with `dplyr`, among them `arrange()` and `summarize()`. Thus, if you load `plyr` after loading `dplyr` (which you do with the `tidyverse`), then these functions will be masked by `plyr`, breaking the code at hand. You will get a warning regarding this when you load `plyr` after `dplyr`. Ideally, don't use `plyr`; everything in it can be done with `dplyr` or `purrr` from the `tidyverse`. If you feel you can't do without `plyr`, load it first, and then the `tidyverse`

Comment: You may also want to look into how [namespaces work in R](https://rfaqs.com/namespace-in-r-language/)

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can split the data.frame and then st_linestring the cbinded columns.

Then it's just plug and play.

```
lapply(split(data, data$ID), \(x) plot(st_linestring(cbind(c(x$start_lon, x$end_lon), 
                                        c(x$start_lat, x$end_lat)))))
```

Here I called plot within it, but you can get rid of the plot call to just get the linestrings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank You @Jahi Zamy. I find your code very interesting. What does the "\\(X)" in the lapply function stand for?

Comment: It stands for function(x)